# How can I make a table of files by looping through each file in the files directory?

Tags: html, browser, blazor

I have made an uploading system, where uploaded midi files gets copied into the wwwroot directory.
After I upload a midi file, I want the page to load and show a table of choosable midi files.

Right now I'm looping through the files in the directory, which I do through the code snippet bellow.

```
public void loadMidiFiles()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            filesList.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }
```

Where `path`  is the wwwroot directory.

The HTMML part

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="loadMidiFiles">Load</button>
<table>
    @foreach (string file in filesList)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@file</th>
            </tr>  
        }
</table>
```

How do i make a table that on page load shows the midi files spread out like a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need a couple of things to flesh this out.

First is a page level variable for your files, and the other is to wire it into one of the page lifecycle events like...

```
@page "/midi-list"

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="loadMidiFiles">Load</button>
<table>
    @foreach (string file in filesList)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@file</th>
            </tr>  
        }
</table>

@code {
    private List<string> filesList;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        loadMidiFiles;
    }

    void loadMidiFiles()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            filesList.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
        }
    }
}
```

here's some more information about lifecycle events:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thank you for the answer and especially the lifecycle page, which helped me a lot.

Comment: I'm happy to help, and glad it worked for you.